# Typescripting custom plugins in Nuxt

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, plugins, nuxt.js

In my Nuxt project, I created a custom plugin file that returns an object. `/helpers/settings`:

```
export const settings = {
  baseURL: 'https://my-site.com',
  ...
};
```

I register this file in `/plugins/settings.ts`:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import { settings } from '~/helpers/settings';

Vue.prototype.$settings = settings;
```

And in `nuxt.config.js`:

```
export default {
  ...
  plugins: [
    '~/plugins/settings',
```

Then, in a component, I can use my plugin like so:

```
export default Vue.extend({
  data() {
    return {
      url: `${this.$settings.baseURL}/some-path`,
```

Everything works as expected, except in that in my console, I get a typescript error from the line that I refer to my plugin in my component:

```
Property '$settings' does not exist on type 'CombinedVueInstance<Vue, unknown, unknown, unknown, Readonly<Record<never, any>>>'.
```

Hence my question: what is the proper way to apply a type to my custom plugin so that I don't get this error every time I use it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html#Augmenting-Types-for-Use-with-Plugins), you'll need to augment the type file for Vue.

Place the following code in a file named `plugin-types.d.ts`.

```
// 1. Make sure to import 'vue' before declaring augmented types
import Vue from 'vue'

// 2. Specify a file with the types you want to augment
//    Vue has the constructor type in types/vue.d.ts
declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
  // 3. Declare augmentation for Vue
  interface Vue {
    $settings: string
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58149550/10002146) also work but I found an easier, though dirtier, way to fix it without the need of adding the `plugin-types.d.ts` file.

Just add a property to you componen with the name of plugin like following:

```
@Component
export default class YourComponent extends Vue {
  private $settings!: string; // your plugin here
  private url: string = `${this.$settings.baseURL}/some-path`
}
```